# How can i copy the contents of a directory located in multiple locations using find command and preserving directory structure?

Tags: bash

I have a folder named `accdb` under multiple directories all under one parent directory `dist`. I want to copy the contents of `accdb` for all directories while preserving the code structure

I succeeded in making the recursive folder structure with:

```
cd ~/dist; find . -name "accdb" -type d -exec mkdir -p -- ~/acc_trial/{} \;
```

But i am failing to copy the contents of `accdb`. This command just makes the structure until directory `accdb`.

I tried

```
find . -name "accdb" -type d -exec mkdir -p -- ~/acc_trial/{} \ && cp -r {} ~/acc_trial/{} \;
```

I get an error:

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: `rsync -R` ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/552120/preserve-directory-tree-while-copying-with-rsync

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible using only a find expression, I'm pretty sure it is not. Besides you must consider that if you have one subfolder named `accdb` inside one `accdb` folder you'll probably get an error, that's why in the script that I've made I decided to use rsync:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST='/home/corronx/provisional/destination_dir'
#Clean destination directory, PLEASE BE CAREFUL IT MUST BE A REMOVABLE DIRECTORY
rm -rf $DEST/*

FIND='test'
LOOK_PATH='/home/corronx/provisional'
FILES=($(find . -type d -name $FIND))


for ((i=0; i<${#FILES[@]};i++))
do
        #Remove first character .
        FILES[$i]=${FILES[$i]:1:${#FILES[$i]}}
        #Create directories in destination path
        mkdir -p $DEST${FILES[$i]}
        rsync -aHz --delete ${FILES[$i]:1:${#FILES[$i]}}/ $DEST${FILES[$i]}
        echo $i
done
```

#### Explanation

First of all I'd recommend using full paths in your script because an `rm -rf` expression inside an script is pretty dangerous (If you want comment that line and delete destination folder before running script).

`DEST`= Destination path.

`FIND`= Subfolder name that your are looking for.

`LOOK_PATH`= Path where you want to execute find

I create an array called `FILES` that contain all folders that returns find expression, after that I just create destination directories and run `rsync` to copy files, I've used `rsync` because I think it is better in case there is any subdirectory with the same name.

**PLEASE BE CAREFUL WITH `rm -rf` expression, if DEST is not set you'll delete everything in your machine**